# HTML code for green arrow?

Tags: html

What is the HTML code for a green arrow? By using

→ original feedback loop

I was able to form a black arrow with a text (original feedback loop) to go along with it but I am unable to change the color of the arrow to green. This is relevant as I am using the color to differentiate a legend.

Comment: are you unable to change the color because you don't know anything about css or is there something else interfering?

Answer (score 1):

You can do using this

```html
<p><span style="color:green">&#8594;</span> original feedback loop</p>
```